# Show the actual raw data + HTTPS headers sent by HttpsURLConnection

Tags: android

I have this simple code to connect to my host:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/getResource");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
m_HttpsConnection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = m_HttpsConnection.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(os);
wr.writeBytes("{\"key\":\"value\"}");
wr.flush();
wr.close();

Log.d("MyActivity", "http raw data: " + conn.toString()); <-- this is what I want to achieve!
```

What I want to see in my logs is the actual HTTP packets that I send to the host like so:

```
POST /getResource/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-control: no-cache
Content-Length: 15

{"key":"value"}
```

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps switch to OkHttp and add the logging interceptor.

Comment: I am sending this from a secured device. So I am kind of reluctant to use a third party app to handle my data.

Comment: OkHttp is not an app. It is a library.

Comment: I meant third party library. Anyway, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I was not able to get the complete raw request headers using OkHttp. However, I was able to get everything for response headers. I added my test results as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both `OkHttpClient` and `HttpsURLConnection`, there is no way to check the complete raw request HTTP packet that you send to a host.

For `OkHttpClient`, this is the best you can do to check the headers:

```
class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();

        logger.info(String.format("Sending request %s",
                request.headers().toString()));

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        logger.info(String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
                response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers()));

        return response;
    }
}
```

Please take note that when you did not set any header (`Request.Builder.header()`), nothing will show in your logs. The same observation holds true for `HttpsURLConnection`. The `HttpsURLConnection.getRequestProperties()` will only show what you have set in `HttpsConnection.setRequestProperty()`.

For HTTP response, it is a different story. You can get the entire raw response headers.

For `HttpsURLConnection` you can use below code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = httpsURLConnection.getHeaderFields();
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

Log.d(TAG, "https response headers: ");
for (String key : keys) {
    List<String> list = map.get(key);
    for (String value : list) {
        Log.d(TAG, "key: " + key + ", value: " + value);
    }
}
```

This gives you everything in your response packet including the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` field:

```
D/MyActivity: key: null, value: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
D/MyActivity: key: Cache-Control, value: private
D/MyActivity: key: Content-Length, value: 20
D/MyActivity: key: Content-Type, value: application/json
D/MyActivity: key: Date, value: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 09:16:06 GMT
D/MyActivity: key: Server, value: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

I believe you can also get the complete response packet for `OkHttpClient`. I did not check.