# How to retain the connection made by HttpsURLConnection

Tags: android

I have this connection:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/resource);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// send bytes here
// receive bytes here

// further send and receive here.
```

What I want to do is retain the `conn` for further send and receive operations a few seconds later. Is this possible with `HttpsURLConnection`? The reason I want to do so is due to the fact that SSL handshake during connection is a slow process and we want to avoid this in our project. And at the same time, we want to leverage the HTTP handling capability of the `HttpsURLConnection` class. TIA.

Comment: sockets would be the answer to your question.... url connection is not meant for this

Comment: how about the http part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible with HttpsURLConnection?

Not directly, sorry.

> The reason I want to do so is due to the fact that SSL handshake during connection is a slow process and we want to avoid this in our project.

[This should be handled behind the scenes](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection#performance). If you do not manually call `disconnect()`, and your server is set up to allow SSL and connection pooling (e.g., HTTP/2), connection pooling should be handled automatically.

If you need more direct control over this sort of thing, use a more modern and flexible HTTP client, such as the OkHttp that [I steered you towards yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592412/show-the-actual-raw-data-https-headers-sent-by-httpsurlconnection).

Comment: I should get your Busy Coder's guide.